# How do I save data across a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server

I'm using Heroku to host a node.js server where a variable that stores the number of times every user that used the site has clicked something on it. When clicked, the variable gets increased by 1. However, Heroku does this thing where inactivity for 15 mins causes the site to go to sleep and everything is reset. I tried to use node.js to write to a file and save it but it seems the files are also reset. Does anyone know a way to get the data saved even after Heroku declares it inactive?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around it, since Heroku gets rid of files after inactivity. You need some external storage like a MongoDB set up somewhere else.